# Delete method couldn't be invoked in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I'm implementing delete user method in my view, This is the destroy method in my users_controller

```
def destroy
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'This user was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

And my view:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', users_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

And the application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

And in the layouts/application.html.erb I have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default' %>
```

And everytime I clicked on the destroy link, it just refreshes and doesn't delete. What I should mention is the view is under superadmins and the superadmins_controller is inherited from users_controller where I wrote the destroy method. I think it might be something wrong with route.rb but I can't come up with a solution. My route.rb looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'visitors#index'
devise_for :users, :path =>'u'
devise_scope :user do
    get '/u/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
  resources :users
  resources :superadmins
end
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE on console**

```
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: Just did. Still the same

Comment: on your console can you check if you are getting any js erros on page load and make sure that jQuery is loaded

Comment: updated now. Seems like there's no route founded

Comment: Did you check what's the actual request sent when you confirm deletion, you can use the Network tab in any of the browsers inspect tool to find out, I'm suspecting that a GET request is sent not DELETE or it's and XHR request not HTTP request which you only handle in your controller + json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change :
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'default' %>`

to : `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

because in your console the first error is `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js")`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your route definitions and your link_to helper (which is specifying `method: :delete`.  Try changing

```
get '/u/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
```

to

```
delete '/u/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
```

Comment: My problem is not with sign out, that works just fine. My problem is with when I manage users, I can't delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is your use of `users_path` rather than the correct `user_path`

so change this

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', users_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

to this

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```